# Running nodejs, expressjs, socket.io application on a real server not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, server

I'm able to successfully run nodejs, expressjs, socket.io and mongodb appplication on my local machine `http://localhost:3000`

Now, I have uploaded the application on the real server that supports nodejs but how can I run the application using the port 3000? So `www.mywebsite.com/MyApp:3000` doesn't work :( Do I have to run in a PORT?

can you please help me?

Here's my server app.js code:

```
var express = require('express');

var  mongoose = require ('mongoose');

var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static('../app/'));
app.use('/bower_components', express.static('../bower_components/'));

var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

//mongodb databse
mongoose.connect ('mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydb', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log (err);
    } else {
        console.log ("Connected to mongodb");
    }
});


io.sockets.on ('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("hello world, I'm running fine!")
});

http.listen(3000, function () {
    'use strict';
});
```

EDIT: if I use port 80, I get this error:

```
 events.js:87
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
                ^
    Error: listen EACCES
        at exports._errnoException (util.js:748:11)
        at Server._listen2 (net.js:1123:19)
        at listen (net.js:1166:10)
        at Server.listen (net.js:1251:5)
      ....etc
```

Comment: Most likely, you want `www.mywebsite.com:3000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run your app on production using your existing node / express code you would naviagate to `http://www.mywebsite.com:3000/MyApp` (assuming your firewall allows port 3000)

You can change the port though to be what ever you want by changing this part of the code:

```
http.listen(3000, function () {
    'use strict';
});
```

The standard port for web is 80. So you could change this to be

```
http.listen(80, function () {
    'use strict';
});
```

And then use your url as normal - `http://www.mywebsite.com/MyApp`

Note: If you have another web server on your server that is using this port already then you are going to have a problem as it will not listen until the port is free. You will have to disabled other web servers listening on port 80 first.
Non-privileged user (not root) can't listen on sockets on ports below 1024 either.

Comment: Thanks, but if I use port 80 I get en error, see my edit

Comment: Also read my note about port 80 being used already. Do you have IIS installed?

Comment: Run `netstat -an | findstr :80` to see if anything is using this port.

Comment: On linux run this instead `netstat -an | grep ':80'` Try running you node shell with elevated permissions too (i.e. sudo..)

Comment: Did you try running node with sudo? Non-privileged user (not root) can't open a listening socket on ports below 1024

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72975/discussion-between-angular-learner-and-haxtbh).